# Soft hyphen (&shy;) breaks center alignment in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to center align some paragraph in a flex box. The text itself should be left aligned.

This works fine. However, a `&shy;` tag seems to break the center alignement of the paragraph:

[image]

Is there a way to keep the center alignment if a word contains such a `&shy;` tag?

Here is the example:
https://jsfiddle.net/k3htx2mr/4/

```
.box {
  background: #227486;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}    
Problem:
<div class="box">
  <p>
    Text with a veryvery&shy;longword.
  </p>
</div>
Desired result:
<div class="box">
  <p>
    Text with a veryvery-<br>longword.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Soft hyphen (shy) This character is not rendered visibly; instead, it suggests a place where the browser might choose to break the word if necessary. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34835882/3536236)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the soft hyphen (which is an HTML entity and not a tag, BTW). Look at the third example below which simply contains a longer text without `br` and `&shy;` elements: It is also left-aligned since it automatically will span the whole available width as soon as it gets longer than one line and is broken automatically.

So the only solution to get what you want is to either limit the width of the `p` tag or to use all `br` tags (so that no line becomes as long as the width of the container - which however is hard if you consider resposiveness).

```css
.box {
  background: #227486;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
Using a soft hyphen:
<div class="box">
  <p>
    Text with a veryveryvery&shy;longword.
  </p>
</div>
Desired result (using a linebreak tag):
<div class="box">
  <p>
    Text with a veryvery-<br>longword.
  </p>
</div>
A longer text without break or soft hyphen:
<div class="box">
  <p>
    And some more text which simply contans more words and therefore will break into several lines.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Soft-hyphen`: `&shy;` tag is not rendered visibly so it is needed to replace that `soft-hyphen` into `<br/>` or some other text like space using javascript as follows.

```js
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML=document.getElementById("text").innerHTML.replace(/\u00AD/g, '<br/>');
```

```css
body {
  background: #1f2227;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "arial", sans-serif;
}

.box {
  background: #227486;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
Problem:
<div class="box">
  <p id="text">
    Text with a veryvery&shy;longword.
  </p>
</div>
Desired result:
<div class="box">
  <p>
    Text with a veryvery-<br>longword.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there no way for this problem with pure css?

Comment: It cannot be done using css because even if using css, the `p` tag width won't change. The goal is to make the `p` tag width to fit the wrapped text and for this, javascript choice is the best.

Comment: @Ilyssis so... simply remove the soft hyphen. It's not really needed, you can replace it with a line breaker